# Histogram bars with different bar colors

Tags: colors, histogram, stata

I would like to get a histogram with alternating gradients of a given color, according to decile breakpoints, as shown in figure below:

[image]

Example data:

```
clear
input float dn3001 double hw0010
  1219000 2823.89408574376
   -16390 520.112200750285
   121010 238.732322261911
   953839 221.316063150235
   465000 247.280750487467
     -870 280.305382323347
    96000 2946.16661611018
    69500  355.33497718705
   113000 1421.43087298696
    30500 616.914514202173
    20000 3389.34765405599
   154000 305.674687642557
   440500 525.694777777734
    56870 1823.24691219821
   330500 376.651172915574
   101000 465.098273950744
 401046.5 660.816203440777
    31872 1693.02190101773
   220345 603.326244510505
   193360 677.527413164373
   196300 568.436679602066
   222640 427.051692314575
   510500 318.557431587468
   131450 1388.72862441839
   122300 532.996690473983
      305 2441.72289873923
   313500 292.610321722557
   184500 2699.67735757755
1615564.6 386.944439319246
   126528 3018.77523617479
   711110 511.604491869939
   127440 256.968118266053
   424900   1620.366555701
    95491 3097.46262561529
   287500 413.119620218929
    70050 2119.47171174278
    75460 299.232446656805
   210500 290.391474820414
   135800 292.141670444933
   119924 303.953183619671
    81075 1568.41438245214
      152 289.175871985445
    73000 2551.12752046544
   246500 327.474430367518
   159960 2350.26463245568
    14522  456.56909870547
   139000 319.451311193507
    68661 2771.34087931684
 214089.7 388.589383036063
   927800 849.088069585408
     7840 1512.71702946577
   140140 852.940547469624
21646.566 2405.47949923772
end
```

The code below produces a graph with uneven bar spread:

```
xtile aux = dn3001 [aw=hw0010], nq(10)
_pctile dn3001[aw=hw0010], nq(10)
sort dn3001 
list dn3001 aux
return list
scalar p10=r(r1)
scalar p20=r(r2)
scalar p30=r(r3)
scalar p40=r(r4)
scalar p50=r(r5)
scalar p60=r(r6)
scalar p70=r(r7)
scalar p80=r(r8)
scalar p90=r(r9)
drop aux
sum dn3001 [aw=hw0010], d
scalar p1=r(p1)
scalar p95=r(p95)
twoway histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p1) & dn3001<scalar(p10),  bcolor(green%20) freq legend(off) ///
    || histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p10) & dn3001<scalar(p20),  bcolor(green) freq legend(off) ///
    || histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p20) & dn3001<scalar(p30),  bcolor(green%20) freq legend(off) /// 
    || histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p30) & dn3001<scalar(p40),  bcolor(green) freq legend(off) ///
    || histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p40) & dn3001<scalar(p50),  bcolor(green%20) freq legend(off) /// 
    || histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p50) & dn3001<scalar(p60),  bcolor(green) freq legend(off) ///
    || histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p60) & dn3001<scalar(p70),  bcolor(green%20) freq legend(off) ///
    || histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p70) & dn3001<scalar(p80),  bcolor(green) freq legend(off) ///
    || histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p80) & dn3001<scalar(p90),  bcolor(green%20) freq legend(off) ///
    || histogram dn3001 if dn3001>=scalar(p90) & dn3001<scalar(p95),  bcolor(green) freq legend(off)
```

[image: Output]

How can I get the same bar width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one potential approach:

```
twoway__histogram_gen dn3001, freq bin(50) generate(b a, replace)

_pctile dn3001 [aw=hw0010], nq(10)

return list

scalars:
                 r(r1) =  20000
                 r(r2) =  30500
                 r(r3) =  68661
                 r(r4) =  75460
                 r(r5) =  96000
                 r(r6) =  126528
                 r(r7) =  159960
                 r(r8) =  196300
                 r(r9) =  440500

generate group = .

forvalues i = 9(-1)1 {
    replace group = `i' if a <= `r(r`i')'
}

replace group = 10 if a > `r(r9)' & _n <= 20
```

```
list a b group in 1 / 20, sepby(group)

     +-----------------------+
     |         a   b   group |
     |-----------------------|
  1. | -70.45375   6       1 |
     |-----------------------|
  2. |  32568.64   4       3 |
  3. |  65207.73   7       3 |
     |-----------------------|
  4. |  97846.82   4       6 |
     |-----------------------|
  5. |  130485.9   9       7 |
     |-----------------------|
  6. |    163125   2       8 |
  7. |  195764.1   4       8 |
     |-----------------------|
  8. |  228403.2   3       9 |
  9. |  261042.3   1       9 |
 10. |  293681.4   1       9 |
 11. |  326320.5   2       9 |
 12. |  391598.7   1       9 |
 13. |  424237.8   2       9 |
     |-----------------------|
 14. |  456876.8   1      10 |
 15. |    522155   1      10 |
 16. |  717989.6   1      10 |
 17. |  913824.1   1      10 |
 18. |  946463.3   1      10 |
 19. |   1207576   1      10 |
 20. |   1599245   1      10 |
     +-----------------------+
```

Result:

```
twoway (bar b a, barwidth(25000) legend(off)) ///
       (bar b a if group == 3, barwidth(25000) color(green)) ///
       (bar b a if group == 9, barwidth(25000) color(red))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is indeed very close to what i'm looking for. Accepted as answer and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

More a comment (or a series of comments) than an answer you seek, but the graph won't fit in a comment.

Your approach looks doomed -- if not to failure, then to extreme difficulty.

1. There is no guarantee whatsoever that any of your quantile bin limits will match any of the histogram bin limits.
2. Similarly, there is no guarantee that the difference between adjacent quantiles is a simple multiple of any histogram bin width you might choose. You might be tempted to fudge this by colouring a bar according to whichever quantile bin was more frequent, but that would be ignoring details. So suppose your histogram bar was for [100, 200) but some values in that interval belong to one quantile bin and some to another: what would you do? And what would you do if 3 or more quantile bins fell within a histogram bar?
3. By specifying multiple histograms without specifying starts or bin widths you are unleashing anarchy. Stata will make separate decisions for each histogram based partly on sample sizes. That's what your code is telling it to do, but not what you want.
4. Your histograms don't know anything about the analytic weights you used.

Beyond that, your question raises all sorts of unnecessary puzzles.

- Why produce `aux` and do nothing with it? It's a point of standard art on SO to show the minimum code necessary to explain your problem.
- You say you are interested in deciles but inconsistently are also working with 1 and 95% percentiles.

Why you have such irregular values with very different weights is unclear but inessential for your immediate question. But all that inclines me to think that you cannot get a histogram like your example graph easily or effectively from your data. You have just 53 data points and so weights make no difference to your being unable to have more than 53 non-empty bins.

How the bin limits fall relative to the data can be shown directly without a histogram.

With your example data (thanks!) I do this

```
xtile aux = dn3001 [aw=hw0010], nq(10)

quantile dn3001, ms(none) mla(aux) mlabpos(0) scheme(s1color) rlopts(lc(none))
```

[image]

I would use a logarithmic scale ordinarily but negative values rule that out.

Here I go beyond strict programming issues, but the question inevitably raises the issues I address.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the advice. I will accept your comment as an answer, since this topic is, like you said, completely doomed. The example data is just a very small sample of what i'm actually working on, but it fails to provide a nice illustration.

Comment: This stacking of twoway graphs was an attempt to overcome the fact that i cannot  get different bar colors inside a single histogram. Ideally I would like to plot a single histogram for my variable of interest and then tell stata "I want dark green bars up to percentile 10", "I want light green bars from percentile 10, up to percentile 20"... and so on. This is actually quite achievable using python, but is turning into a stata nightmare. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: What you want requires superimposition of two histograms, not ten. But you still have to deal with irregular bin limits for quantiles. If this appears easier in Python, then I have to guess that Python is doing something a bit different from what you are asking. (I have just edited my answer to flag yet another problem.)

Comment: The difficulties I raise are matters of principle about meshing histograms and quantile bins and transcend choice of software.

Comment: These difficulties would be avoided by stacking histograms for each quantile bin, but the result, although much easier to program, would predictably be messy.